# Reading the same file twice in the code in C

Tags: c, file, csv, readfile, c-strings

If I am reading first line of a file and store in some variable and if I read the same file again and store in different array, Will my array skip the first row ?

```
a1,a2,a3,a4,a5
b1,b2,b3,b4,b5
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
d1,d2,d3,d4,d5
e1,e2,e3,e4,e5
```

My code looks Like this

```
    FILE* fp1 = fopen("test.csv","r");
    if(fp1 == NULL)
    {
      printf("Failed to open file\n");
      return 1;
    }

    fscanf(fp1,"%[^\n]",variable); 
    while((fscanf(fp1,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n",C1,C2,C3,C4,C5)>0))
    {

        some function()     

    }
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
       printf("%s\t", C1[i]);
       printf("%s\n", C2[i]);
    }
```

My output starts from 2nd line of File i.e.,

```
C1[i] = {b1,c1,d1,e1}  but not a1
C2[i] = {b2,c2,d2,e2}  but not a2
```

Can someone give a brief why the first line is being skipped ?

Thanks,

Comment: try rewind the file, i.e. fp1.rewind(). it will then point back to the start of file

Comment: Nothing is being skipped. You're not "reading the file again". You read the first line and did one thing with it, then you read the second through last lines and did a different thing with them.

Comment: @chris : OP is using C. So I think call would be like `rewind(fp1);`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions,
@hobbs : My Question is if I use fscanf(fp1) for second time, Will it read from the second line or from first line again? Thanks

Comment: `fscanf(fp1,"%*[^\n]%*c");` : skip first line.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild my bad, been writing too much c++ lately clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsequent calls to fscanf from a file will read further into the file, unless *rewind*ed unless the stream isn't rewindable, like stdin.